# inline-block content shows different results in different browsers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, responsiveness

I have a responsive form element which is supposed to be inline with a title, like so:
[image]

which is fine in Firefox because this is what I'm looking for.
But when we see the same code in Chrome (edit, same results in Blisk, Yandex and maybe all webkit browsers, along with MS Edge and IE11), this is what I get:

[image]

**The code:**

```css
h1,
form {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
}
.field {
  display: table-cell;
}
.field,
input {
  width: 100%;
}
input,
.btn {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>Inline title</h1>
<form action="">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Or, take a look at [the code here (Codepen.io)](https://codepen.io/Drift/pen/akgoow).
Does FF and Chrome handle the CSS differently? I feel that Chrome is showing the correct layout considering that the `.field` class has `display: table-cell;`, but I'm not sure about that. Is there a way to achieve what Firefox has shown in Chrome as well without removing the responsive nature of the `input field`?

Thanks.

Comment: wait--why is my question voted to close?

Comment: Okay thanks @Paulie_D . I was unaware of the new requirements. The Stack Snippet is up.

Comment: can you use `position` with fixed `width` for your `form` like this [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/rLENKk?editors=0110) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the property: `table-cell` and make sure that everything is `inline-block`:

```
h1,
form {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
}
.field {
  display: inline-block; /* instead of table-cell > inline-block */
}
input,
.btn {
  padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

SEE demo here: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZPGkL)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `table-cell` just use `float:left` and remove the `width` from `field` class.

```css
h1,
form {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
}
.field {
  float: left;/* Use floating here */
}
.field,
input {
  /*width: 100%;*/
}
input,
.btn {
  padding: 10px 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Inline title</h1>
<form action="">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```